# How can I see when someone is available on certain days?

Tags: php

I am making a website where you can reserve spots, but for certain spots there need to be someone there. Earlier I asked a question about how to count how many people are available on certain days, for example: on monday there are 2 people available. But now I want that if there is atleast 1 person available on a specific day in the week that you will get a message saying that there is someone there.

But my code doesn't do that, it keeps saying that there is someone available even if there isn't. My code here:

```
if(array_sum([$totalMonday, $totalTuesday, $totalWednesday, $totalThursday, $totalFriday]) > 0){
      echo 'someone is available';
} else{
      echo 'no one is available';
}
```

The **$totalMonday, $totalThursday, etc.** are specified earlier in the code and they count whenever someone is availabe, for example:

```
echo '<b>Monday: </b>';
if(!empty($presentie["workMonday"])) {
      ++$totalMonday;
      echo $presentie["workMonday"];;
} else{
      echo 'not available';
}
```

So I don't know what I am doing wrong, if something is unclear, please tell me, I find it hard to explain what is wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear. You say "_I want that if there is atleast 1 person available on a specific day in the week_", but in your code, you are summing up the total for _every day in the week_, not a specific day. You also ask "_How can I see when someone is available on certain days?_", but you already have variables for each day containing a value of how many people are available, right?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton
What if i change it like this:
`
        if($totalMonday > 0 || $totalTuesday > 0 || $totalWednesday > 0 || $totalThursday > 0 || $totalFriday > 0){
            echo 'someone is available';
        } else{
            echo 'no one is available';
        }
`
And yes, i do, but I mean it in a way of me getting a certain message when someone is available on the day that I choose. Hope this makes it a bit more clear

Comment: So you want to display "someone is available" if someone is available any day of the week?

Comment: No, only the day that I choose, for example, if i choose a date and that date is on a  monday, but there is no one available on monday is should get a message saying that no one is available

Comment: In your code, is `++$totalMonday;` inside a loop? Otherwise, it will only ever equal `1` (And that is only if `!empty($presentie["workMonday"])`). Is that on purpose?

Comment: All the way on top of my code i have a variable that is $totalMonday = 0. After that it shows all the people in a foreach and everytime a day is not empty it will add 1. So i think it is in a loop yeh

Comment: Okay. Writing something up. Few more questions, in a comment you said "_only the day that I choose_" - How exactly do you choose the date, as a user? Is this on the same page, but after the loop? Different page?

Comment: Above it i have a form where you choose a date with the form input="date". Also it is on the same page and before the loop

Comment: If it's before the loop, those variables will always equal 0. PHP executes sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm assuming you have several of the same if/else statements that match the one you have in your 2nd code snippet. We can clean those up by using an additional loop in your code. I'll also show you how to use an array instead of creating a separate variable for each day.

Above your loop, create an array where each key corresponds with a day of the week. (Replace all of your `$total{DAY} = 0;` variable declarations with this)

```
$days = [
    'Monday' => 0,
    'Tuesday' => 0,
    'Wednesday' => 0,
    'Thursday' => 0,
    'Friday' => 0
];
```

Now, we can replace your if/else statements which used to increase the `$total{DAY}` variables. Replace ALL of those if/else statements with this:

```
foreach(array_keys($days) as $day) {
    echo '<b>{$day}: </b>';
    if(!empty($presentie["work{$day}"])) {
          ++$days[$day];
          echo $presentie["work{$day}"];;
    } else{
          echo 'not available';
    }
}
```

This 9 lines of code does the exact same thing as your previous ~35 lines of code.

---

Now, onto your actual question. You said in a comment that the output you are asking for in your question is "*...on the same page and before the loop*". This is a problem, because your loop is what increases those value, there is no way to access them before the loop. You'll have to put it *after* the loop. Here is how you can do it after the loop:

```
//replace with the name of your date select element]
$date = $_POST['date'];

//using `date()`, get the day of the week of the selected date. (Monday-Friday)
$day_of_week = date('l', strtotime($date));

if($days[$day_of_week] > 0) {
    echo $days[$day_of_week] . " people available.";
} else {
    echo "Not Available";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, everything works fine apart from the last code snippet, it does not matter what i choose for day it keeps saying "Not Available", but the rest works really well and i am really thankfull ^^

Comment: @Orbo12345 Did you put the code _after_ your previous loop? Did you change `$_POST['date']` to match the name of your input element on your form?

Comment: I kept the order you sent it, first the array with the days, then the foreach and after that the date checker thing. I also changed the `$_POST['date']` to how i have it in my form

Comment: Could it maybe because of me changing the language in the array, because the `date('l')` thing is automatically in English but my site is in Dutch?

Comment: @Orbo12345 Yes, that could be a problem because it uses the English word to return the value. It could be fixed by changing all of the days in the `$days` array to the dutch variant.

Comment: Yeh i have done that, but the `date('l', strtotime($inputDate))` is automatically in English, and everything that i try to put it in Dutch does not work

Comment: @Orbo12345 It may be in your interest to just leave them as english for the variables. I can update my answer to include a way to add different text for the display of the day? I'm not sure if `date()` has a way to change it to the dutch variant.

Comment: @Orbo12345 Actually ,it looks like you could use `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');` to convert it to the dutch variant. You may have to contact your host to get that locale installed though.

Comment: I changed the days in the array back to English but it still isn't working, also i am working on a localhost

Comment: @Orbo12345 Could you do some troubleshooting for me? I need to know the value of `var_dump($day_of_week)` and also the value of `var_dump($days)` right before the if/else from my last code snippet.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zZlR0xN, here it is, sorry it took so long

Comment: @Orbo12345 It looks like `date('l')` is still returning the english phrase, hence why it isn't working.